# Vector changing (smoothing) with Isend/Irecv MPI c++

Tags: c++, vector, mpi, nonblocking, smoothing

I have a task to smooth a vector via the next formula

x [ i ] = ( x [ i - 1 ] + x [ i + 1 ] ) / 2

using Isend/Irecv MPI.

Initial vector consists of N elements and x [ 0 ] = x [ N / 2 - 1 ] = x [ N - 1 ] = 1. These elements are constant.

I send parts of an initial vector from master to every slave process. Then every process smoothes its part. The point is that I need to exchange boundary elements of every process every time they are updated.

For example, if I have 4 processes (including master)

- master: 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
- 1 process will get: 1 0 0
- 2 process will get: 0 1 0
- 3 process will get: 0 0 0 1

After one iteration:

- 1 process will get: 1 0.5 0.25
- 2 process will get: 0.5 1 0.5
- 3 process will get: 0 0 0.5 1

Exchanging:

- 1 process sends its last element to 2 process.
- 2 process sends its first element to 1 process and its last element to 3 process.
- 3 process sends its first element to 2 process.

My code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define iter_num 1
#define vec_size 10
using namespace std;

void one_proc(int iter) {
    // single program
}

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int rank, size;

vector <double> main_vector(vec_size);
main_vector[0] = main_vector[(vec_size / 2)-1] = main_vector[vec_size - 1] = 1;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (size == 1 || size==2)
{
    one_proc(iter_num);
    MPI_Finalize();
    exit(0);
}
MPI_Request request;
MPI_Status status;

int proc_amount = size - 1; //exclude the master
int temp_size = ((vec_size % proc_amount) ? (vec_size / proc_amount + 1) : (vec_size / proc_amount));
vector <double> temp(temp_size);

if (rank == 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= proc_amount; i++) {
        temp.assign(main_vector.begin() + (i - 1)*vec_size / proc_amount, main_vector.begin() + (i*vec_size / proc_amount));
        MPI_Isend(&temp[0], temp.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
    }
}
else
{
    temp[temp_size - 1] = -1; // kludge. is used when vector can't be divided into equal parts 
    MPI_Irecv(&temp[0], temp_size, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
    if (temp[temp_size - 1] == -1)
    {
        temp.pop_back();
    }
}


double first, last;
for (int i = 0; i < iter_num; i++)
{
    if (rank == 1)
    {
        first = temp[temp.size() - 1];
        //send last element to 2 process as first
        MPI_Isend(&first, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        //receive first element from 2 process as last
        MPI_Irecv(&last, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
        temp.push_back(last);

        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
        {
            if (j != 0 && j != temp.size() - 1) {
                if (temp[j] != 1) {
                    temp[j] = (temp[j - 1] + temp[j + 1]) / 2;
                }
            }
        }
        temp.pop_back();
        first = temp[temp.size() - 1];

        cout << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.size(); k++) {
            cout << rank << " " << temp[k] << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (rank > 1 && rank < proc_amount)
    {
        last = temp[0];
        MPI_Isend(&last, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        MPI_Irecv(&first, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        temp.insert(temp.begin(), first);

        first = temp[temp.size() - 1];
        MPI_Isend(&first, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);


        MPI_Irecv(&last, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        temp.push_back(last);

        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
        {
            if (j != 0 && j != temp.size() - 1) {
                if (temp[j] != 1) {
                    temp[j] = (temp[j - 1] + temp[j + 1]) / 2;
                }
            }
        }


        temp.erase(temp.begin());
        temp.pop_back();

        cout << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.size(); k++) {
            cout << rank << " " << temp[k] << endl;
        }

    }
    else if (rank == proc_amount)
    {
        last = temp[0];
        MPI_Isend(&last, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, proc_amount - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        MPI_Irecv(&first, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, proc_amount - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
        MPI_Wait(&request, &status);

        temp.insert(temp.begin(), first);
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
        {
            if (j != 0 && j != temp.size() - 1) {
                if (temp[j] != 1) {
                    temp[j] = (temp[j - 1] + temp[j + 1]) / 2;
                }
            }
        }
        temp.erase(temp.begin());
        cout << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.size(); k++) {
            cout << rank << " " << temp[k] << endl;
        }
    }

}
// gathering
MPI_Finalize();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

There is **no speed-up** because processes communicate a lot.

I know that my solution isn't efficient, so I will pe pleased if you advise me **how to improve** it or **suggest another approach** (only point-to-point communication).

Comment: algorithm question: why are you smoothing with an already smoothed value? the `i - 1` value needs to be processed before you can process `i`. that means you have to wait for the process before it to be done before you can start processing, making the split useless. How does the first iteration for process 2 gets `0.625` for the first value if process 1 isn't done yet.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x yes, you're right. those results are for the single program, not for parallel. In fact, after one iteration, I get
1 process: 1 0.5 0.25;
2 process: 0.5 1 0.5;
3 process: 0 0 0.5 1.
So actually my code works correctly. The problem was with my algorithm understanding. Thank you! I'll edit the question because I still want to improve my solution.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. In that case, why don't you send a larger chunk to each process? (+1 to either side) That way, they can calculate their values without cross-talk

Comment: note `MPI_I{Recv,Send}()` immediately followed by `MPI_Wait()` is equivalent to `MPI_{Recv,Send}()`. at first glance your program will deadlock with 5 tasks or more. you can fix that with `MPI_Sendrecv(src=rank+1, dst=rank-1)` followed by `MPI_Sendrecv(src=rank-1, dst=rank+1)`. this can be used on all ranks with MPI_PROC_NULL when no data should be sent/received.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x If there are other params, f.i., more than 1 iteration, sending larger chunk won't be helpful - I'll still need to share updated boundary elements.